# Google Maps API Call Limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

How do I set a limit on the number of calls so that I am not charged for the Google Maps API on my clients website?

I have searched through the pages and I keep circling around and not finding how to set a limit so I am not charged a fee.  I see that they give you 25000 a month but I want to ensure I do not exceed that.

Thank you Lisa

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Platform FAQ has a dedicated section that answers the question: `How do I avoid a large bill if my usage unexpectedly increases?` under [Usage limits and billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits).